# Extraer los 3 primeros valores de mi resultado

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes tengo 3 input donde tengo con sus id y luego un código javascript el cual detecto lo que tiene los input y hago la operación pertinente y lo muestro en otro input.

El detalle es que del primer input el cual el usuario ingresa una cierta cantidad por ejemplo 3,400 yo solo quiero agarrar los valores antes de la coma y un valor mas después de la coma osea que me agarre 34 para poder hacer la operación correctamente.

Estuve leyendo sobre split(), explode() pero no se como aplicarlo.

```js
function op1(){
    try{
        var v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value) || 0,
                v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value) || 0;
        document.getElementById("v3").value = v1 * v2;
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=3><B>Leucocito</B></td>
    <td class='text-right'><input type="text" id="v1" oninput="op1()" style="width:50px; font-weight:bold;"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=3><B>Monocito</B></td>
    <td class='text-right'><input type="text" id="v2" oninput="op1()" style="width:50px; font-weight:bold;"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=3><B>Monocito 2</B></td>
    <td class='text-right'><input type="text" id="v3" style="width:50px; font-weight:bold;"/></td>
</tr>
```

quiero que dependiendo de la cantidad que ingrese el usuario en el input 1 me devuelva en el input 3 los 3 primeros valores, por ejemplo 5800 * 9 = 52200 quiero que solo me apareza 522, de igual forma si es 127,800 * 6 = 766,800 me detecte o me aparezca 766.

Si me pudieran apoyar sobre esto por favor de como sera se los super agradecería.

Comment: El escenario que describes es extraño. ¿Por qué permites escribir valores para luego **desechar** una parte de ellos? ¿Qué es lo que justifica lo que parece una práctica sin sentido?

Comment: es que el detalle es que si el usuario mete en el primer input con coma por ejemplo 5,800 y en el segundo input mete 9 como le hago para que me tome los números delante de la coma y un solo numero o dígito después de la coma???

Comment: No entendí lo que comentas. Pero es evidente que sería mucho mejor controlar las entradas del usuario, no permitiendo que éste escriba cualquier cosa en los input.

Comment: si osea el usuario ingresa la cantidad 5,800 o n cantidad, quiero que al multiplicar por la segunda cantidad esta agarre el numero antes de la coma osea el 5 y un numero solo un numero o digito despues de la coma osea 8 y lo detecte como 58 para asi poder multiplicar con la cantidad ingresada en el segundo input, por que si ingreso ahora con la parte del codigo que me comento y ayudo el usuario mas abajo, si ingreso 5800 x 9 me da 522 y si le pongo coma 5,800 me da 45. quiero que omita la coma y me agarre lo que describo mas arriba.

Comment: Eso es lo raro. Que para escribir un `58` el usuario tenga que escribir `5,800` ¿?  ¿No es mejor evitar las comas en ese input y que el usuario escriba `58`  sin más?

Comment: el usuario en este caso un quimico reporta en el input x cantidad en este caso 5,800 pero para hacer los calculos correspondientes y sacar el valor de Monocito 2 en este caso el input 3 solo agarra los valores que te comente osea 58 pero en la bd el quiere que se guarde 5,800 y de el resultado que me apoyaron en resolver aqui mismo, pero ya quedo estimado, ya lo pude sacar como lo querian. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que mi respuesta se ha de ayuda. Entiendo que deseas mostrar solo los tres primeros caracteres del resultado de la multiplicación. Para ello puedes usar El método **slice()**. Este extrae una sección de una cadena y devuelve una cadena nueva. Por ejemplo:

```
var numero= 12345;
//Lo convertimos a string
var numero_a_string= numero+"";
//Usamos slice(parametro1,parametro2). Parametro1 es el index por donde iniciaremos a leer la cadena, siendo 0 el primero. El segundo parámetro es donde se finalizara a leer la cadena, siendo 3 el aplicable al ejemplo.
var resultado= numero_a_string.slice(0,3);
//El resultado de 12345 será 123
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo aplicado a tu pregunta en el siguiente código.

```js
function op1(){
    try{
        var v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value) || 0,
                v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value) || 0;
        var mult= v1 * v2;
        var txt= mult+"";
        document.getElementById("v3").value = txt.slice(0,3) ;
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=3><B>Leucocito</B></td>
    <td class='text-right'><input type="text" id="v1" oninput="op1()" style="width:50px; font-weight:bold;"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=3><B>Monocito</B></td>
    <td class='text-right'><input type="text" id="v2" oninput="op1()" style="width:50px; font-weight:bold;"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=3><B>Monocito 2</B></td>
    <td class='text-right'><input type="text" id="v3" style="width:50px; font-weight:bold;"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Usiel de verdad que estuve batallando para poner de la forma que lo haces tu, lo intente con substr() y split pero no me salia, gracias por enorme favor mi estimado. Ahora una duda no mas eso es en el detalle que el usuario ingresa en el primer input la cantidad sin coma pero si el usuario teclea con coma como precede ahi? es que si le pongo coma me da otra cantidad como lo omitiria?

Comment: Para eliminar la coma prueba usar el método *Replace()*. Para usar este método debes convertir la variable v1 a string, luego eliminas la coma con replace() y finalizas convirtiendo el string nuevamente a Int para proseguir con la multiplicacion. Con replace() conviertes 5,800 a 5800 pues eliminaras la coma de la cadena, pienso que es una posible solución. Te dejo un enlace donde se explica a detalle este método: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Muchas gracias mi estimado si ya lo aplique y me resulto me lei la documentacion que me propircionaste y ya pude realizarlo adecuadamente.